# Simple C# Metro StreamSocket example

Tags: c#, sockets, microsoft-metro

I'm posting this because I've already wasted one day searching and programming a thing that should really be simple to set up even in Metro.

I'm looking for a C# StreamSocket example that can connect to a socket, read data from the socket (I don't exactly know when data will arrive, so I always want to listen for new data) and write data to it at arbitrary times. This has been an easy task to accomplish in every programming language framework (including .NET), but I can't do this in Metro without getting exceptions (`ObjectDisposedExceptions` when trying to write while simultaneously waiting for incoming data).

The Metro examples given are too simple since they know exactly when to poll for data. This simple task should really be possible!

Answer (score 1):

If you set up a DataReader on the incoming StreamSocket you can set it's InputStreamOptions to InputStreamOptions.Partial. This will allow you to read the data as it arrives and dynamically decide how to process it.

```
var dr = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
dr.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
var stringHeader = await dr.LoadAsync(512);
```

This post also mentions it http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2012/04/07/streamsocket-example-c-metro/